# LG Monitor 27" Drivers

Tags: drivers, sound, multiple-monitors

I recently switched to 2 LG monitors (27MN60T - https://www.costco.com/lg-27%22-class-fhd-ips-freesync-monitor.product.100676476.html)

I couldn't find drivers to the screens. The screens work, but I can't hear the sound out of them (they have a small speaker). My OS recognizes it (I'm using HDMI to connect them), but I couldn't hear anything.
Also, even though the settings between the two screens are similar, one appears to be a bit brighter.

Thus, I assume that installing drivers will help, but I can't find any (there's for Windows or Mac, I have Ubuntu 18.04)
*I have an NVIDIA 2080 GPU, and all of the NVIDIA parts were installed (way before these screens)

Comment: There are no drivers for monitors. And according to LG no speaker either: https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27mn60t-w-led-monitor

Comment: Thank you @ChanganAuto! On the settings sound setting it shows me the two screens (HDMI connection) as an output, so I understood it's a speaker. Also, the fact that one screen is slightly brighter annoyed me (the settings are similar).